# How to center horizontally a div within an li in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple drop down menu, like so:

```
<ul class="nav multilevel">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><span>item 3 +</span>
        <div class="cntLevel level">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">short item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">very long menu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">medium menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with the following CSS:

```
ul {margin:0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

.nav {
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
}

.nav > li:hover {
    background-color: #ececec;
}

.nav > li > a, .nav > li > span {
    font-size: 20px; color: #333; text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.multilevel .cntLevel {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; top: 83px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.cntLevel {
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
}

.level li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.level li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    text-align: left; text-decoration: none;
}

.level li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

All works perfectly! Here's the jsfiddle as prove:

https://jsfiddle.net/jq2ub0jr/1/

So, what's the problem. Here it is:

I want to center the submenu (drop down menu) to the `<li>` (list item). Right now, it's right aligned. I can probably achive it by declaring a fixed width and a negative margin-left width a left property. But, i definitely don't want to add a fixed width.

How to center my drop down submenu with the `<li>` ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you need some JS. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/y7hynzze/1/

Comment: To resize correctly when window size changes: https://jsfiddle.net/y7hynzze/2/

Comment: i was afraid of that. So, js it is! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container (`li`) is relatively positioned.

Your submenu `div` (child of `li`) is absolutely positioned.

To center the submenu all you need to do is add...

```
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

... to the submenu `div`.

Then you need a width. But you don't want a fixed width. So add a minimum width:

```
min-width: 200px;
```

So the style rule becomes:

```
.multilevel .cntLevel {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 0; remove this */
    top: 83px;
    z-index: 100;

    /* NEW */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    min-width: 200px;
    }
```

The submenu is now centered and will expand with longer text.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jq2ub0jr/6/

Comment: This solution doesn't adapt to the lenght of the text. What if the submenu text items are short or very large? i.e.: https://jsfiddle.net/jq2ub0jr/4/

Comment: I revised my answer. The submenu is now centered and expands with longer link items. It has a minimum width set to 200px, but you can change that if you prefer.